VISION has no attribute enums
I am trying to use googles cloud vision api to generate captions for image.
I tried to annotate the image using the following piece of code:
from google.cloud import vision
from google.cloud.vision_v1 import types


client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient.from_service_account_json('service_account_key.json')

file_name = 'Images/man.jpg'
with open(file_name, 'rb') as image_file:
    content = image_file.read()

image = types.Image(content=content)
response = client.annotate_image({
    'image': image,
    'features': [{'type': vision.enums.Feature.Type.LABEL_DETECTION}]
})

captions = []
for annotation in response.label_annotations:
    captions.append(annotation.description)

print("Generated captions for the image:")
for caption in captions:
    print(caption)


And the error i received was
'features': [{'type': vision.enums.Feature.Type.LABEL_DETECTION}]
AttributeError: module 'google.cloud.vision' has no attribute 'enums'

vision is an enumeration, to acces the LABEL_DETECTION value you can use directly `vision.Feature.Type.LABEL_DETECTION.
